# Is it allowed to return a moved object as a const lvalue reference?

Tags: c++, move

Is it allowed to return a moved value as a const lvalue reference?

```
include<string>
using namespace std;

class C {
private:
  string s;
public:
  const string &release() {
    return move(s);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes but it won't do anything.

The `std::move` function is just a cast to a rvalue reference. So in effect:

```
std::string s;
std::move(s); // returns std::string&& to `s`
```

So it just returns a reference to the object you pass in.

So in your code, you create an rvalue reference to your string `s`, but you bind that reference to a `std::string const&`, which cannot be moved from.

You'd be better simply returning the reference directly:

```
const string &release() {
    return s;
}
```

Or return by move (using exchange):

```
std::string release() {
    return std::exchange(s, std::string{});
    // s valid to be reused, thanks to std::exchange
}
```

The last solution would be to return an rvalue reference, but I wouldn't do that, as it won't guarantee the reference to be moved from.

Answer (score 0):

No, and I don't see why you would want to. `std::move` is like a cast, to the rvalue-reference type. The point of rvalue references returned from `std::move` is for their corresponding values to be *moved* into another object efficiently, possibly changing the original object in the process. A const lvalue reference would not allow you to change the object, so it can't be moved from.